# Hint 'noexpand' on object 'View_CMS_Tree_Joined'

Tags: sql, sql-server, kentico

I'm about to try an upgrade from Kentico 9 to 10. I had to change a column from varchar to nvarchar.

To do this I had to update an index so it didn't use the column and then remove a view, then added the view back in after I updated the column, then updated the index again

Now when I go onto the site I get this error:

```
Hint 'noexpand' on object 'View_CMS_Tree_Joined' is invalid. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Hint 'noexpand' on object 'View_CMS_Tree_Joined' is invalid.
```

How do I fix this so I can start the upgrade?

Thanks

Comment: `NOEXPAND` can't be applied to views that aren't indexed. Looks like in your operations an index that was previously present on the view got dropped, or you forgot to script it when you removed the view. Although you can "fix" things by removing the `WITH (NOEXPAND)` hint in the query that's failing, maintaining the performance of the system probably requires the presence of this index.

Comment: Ahh I see, I will restore the original database and see what I can find

Comment: That was it thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was missing an index for the view, I thought that right clicking > script view as > create to new query editor window would give me the code to recreate the view and it's indexes but it only created one of the two indexes.